# Calling variable within an __init__ function aren't defined in my other class methods

Tags: python

I know this is a basic question and I have no doubt that it has been answered but I cant find any good info anywhere, so:

I have a list of methods that work wonderfully when outside of a class and when variables are declared globally. However, when I try to contain the methods and variables within a class I run into all sorts of errors concerning the variables.

```
class AudioFeatures(object):

def __init__(self, track, sr):
    self.track = track
    self.sr = sr       
    hop_length = 2048
    frame_length_in_seconds = 10        
    frame_length = sr*frame_length_in_seconds
    final_sample = int(librosa.get_duration(track)*sr)
    full_rms = librosa.feature.rms(track, frame_length=frame_length, hop_length=hop_length, center=True)
    std_rms = np.std(full_rms)
    rms_selection = std_rms + (std_rms-(std_rms*(1-std_rms)))
    return


def find_nearest(self, array, value):
    array = array
    idx = (np.abs(array - value)).argmin()
    return idx

def get_min_energy_sample(self, track, sr):
    min_value = np.mean(full_rms) - rms_selection
    min_value_loc = find_nearest(full_rms, min_value)
    min_energy_frame_start = librosa.frames_to_samples(min_value_loc, hop_length=hop_length)
    min_energy_frame_end = min_energy_frame_start + frame_length


    #check to make sure the frame is 10seconds long otherwise set frame to final 10 seconds
    if min_energy_frame_end > final_sample:
        min_energy_sample = track[(final_sample-frame_length): final_sample]
    else:
        min_energy_sample = track[min_energy_frame_start: min_energy_frame_end]

    return min_energy_sample

temp_track = AudioFeatures(file_loc, sr) #this works fine
temp_track.get_min_energy_sample()
```

when running this i am told that full_rms (which is the first variable referenced from the class in the get_min_energy_sample) is not defined. I've tried every combination of self. that I can think of. Any help would be wonderful.

Comment: Start by fixing your indentation and posting a [mcve]

Comment: to call them: `self.function_name()`

Comment: `rms_selection` (and possible other variables) is local to `__init__`. If you want it available in other methods, you have to make it an instance attribute, like `track` and `sr`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remember to store information that you will need to use in the methods as attributes, and then reference them using `self.`, like so:

```
class AudioFeatures(object):

    def __init__(self, track, sr):
        self.track = track
        self.sr = sr       
        self.hop_length = 2048
        frame_length_in_seconds = 10        
        self.frame_length = sr*frame_length_in_seconds
        self.final_sample = int(librosa.get_duration(track)*sr)
        self.full_rms = librosa.feature.rms(track, frame_length=self.rame_length, hop_length=hop_length, center=True)
        std_rms = np.std(self.full_rms)
        self.rms_selection = std_rms + (std_rms-(std_rms*(1-std_rms)))

    def find_nearest(self, array, value):
        idx = (np.abs(array - value)).argmin()
        return idx

    def get_min_energy_sample(self, track, sr):
        min_value = np.mean(self.full_rms) - self.rms_selection
        min_value_loc = find_nearest(self.full_rms, min_value)
        min_energy_frame_start = librosa.frames_to_samples(min_value_loc, hop_length=self.hop_length)
        min_energy_frame_end = min_energy_frame_start + self.frame_length


        #check to make sure the frame is 10seconds long otherwise set frame to final 10 seconds
        if min_energy_frame_end > self.final_sample:
            min_energy_sample = track[(self.final_sample-self.frame_length): self.final_sample]
        else:
            min_energy_sample = track[min_energy_frame_start: min_energy_frame_end]

        return min_energy_sample
```

Answer (score 0):

@ATony is correct, but let's look at a simpler example, cut down to demonstrate the core issue.

```py
>>> class A(object):
...     def __init__(self):
...             self.foo = 42
...             bar = 27
...     def baz(self):
...             print(self.foo)
...             print(bar)
... 
>>> a = A()
>>> a.baz()
42
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 7, in baz
NameError: global name 'bar' is not defined
>>>
```

Now compare this to the following, where both `foo` and `bar` are attributes of `self`. Now we can access both of them from other methods.

```py
>>> class A(object):
...     def __init__(self):
...             self.foo = 42
...             self.bar = 27
...     def baz(self):
...             print(self.foo)
...             print(self.bar)
... 
>>> a = A()
>>> a.baz()
42
27
>>>
```